# How to convert ISO Date time format to a specified format during AJAX call

Tags: ajax, date, time, datetime-format, iso

dateVal = eval(ajaxData)[i]['ISODateTime'];

Now , How to convert ISO Date time format to a specified format during  AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an ISO datetime string to an arbitrary format in Javascript, you should create a new [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and use [its' methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Getter) to construct the new date string.

The date string you are starting with can be everything that [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) can handle, namely:

> A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).

For example, to format an ISO datetime string to a format resembling `dd-mm-yy` do the following:

```
var d = new Date(dateVal);
var dateString = d.getDate()
    + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) // months are zero-based
    + "-" + d.getYear();
```

If this looks as much like tedious work to you than to me, have a look at the magnificent [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library that is really helpful in parsing and formatting dates.